# jquery problem => change not working with append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem of my jquery code
html append :

```
      html = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
      html += '  <td class="text-left image-upload"><a href="" id="thumb-image' + image_row + '"data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="{{ placeholder }}" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" /></a><input type="file" class="uploadImage" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="input-image' + image_row + '" /></td>';
      html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][sort_order]" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_sort_order }}" class="form-control" /></td>';
      html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#image-row' + image_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_remove }}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
      html += '</tr>';

      $('#images tbody').append(html);
```

The problem is when append this row and use ON('CLICK', '.class', function(){}) it not working , and i can't get solution of this problem , any help it will be good!

Jquery Function :

```
    $('.image-upload').on('change', '.uploadImage',function(e){
      console.log('run change img');
      const thisFile = this.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var img = $(this).parent().find('img');
      reader.onload = function(e){
        console.log(reader);
        img.attr('src', this.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(thisFile);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use event delegation, the element you bind the handler to has to be a static element, not something that's added dynamically. Since you're adding `.image-upload` dynamically, you can't bind the delegated event to that. It needs to be a static container element. Since you append these to `#images`, you should use that.

```
$('#images').on('change', '.uploadImage',function(e){
  console.log('run change img');
  const thisFile = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var img = $(this).parent().find('img');
  reader.onload = function(e){
    console.log(reader);
    img.attr('src', this.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(thisFile);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working and thank you for explaining the solution